# Is it possible to use NewsstandKit.framework in a non–Newsstand app?

Tags: ios, asynchronous, download, background-process, newsstand-kit

Before going all the hassle coding a generic asynchronous, queued, background running file download library with pause, resume and cancel features, I was wondering if is it possible using some of the already available similar features of `NewsstandKit.framework` in a non–Newsstand app and publish it on the App Store?

In case the answer is not a plain "no", I would like to know which features would be okay using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is unfortunately, no.

Also, you're not going to get background downloading unless you are using Newsstand. They're the only apps allowed to download whilst the app is not open.

Comment: I guess you can do background as documented [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20)

Comment: Not downloading. You can't do that unless you are a newsstand app.

Comment: Please checkout question entitled "How do I keep requests running in the background after the app has been dismissed?" [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-FAQ)

Comment: Yes, you get 10 minutes, but that's all. Fine, it might be enough time to do the download, but it's not going to be a full solution.

Comment: Oh well, I didn't know that 10 minutes limit and since there doesn't seem to be another way of doing this, I guess I will consider continue downloading in that time period and eventually save what's downloaded so far hoping to resume next time app comes back on. Thanks again!